# database vacuum to avoid transaction wrap around

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

Platform Heroku
PG version 13

I have a very busy database and it is reaching near transaction wrap around.

At this point I really want to do the vacuum manually.
My question is that if I do manual vacuuming of individual tables then I can see that the txid restores to its minimum value. But the global txid is not changed.

Is the individual vacuuming of tables enough ?
Do I still have to do vacuum database ?

Comment: You have to vacuum the entire database. If you have enough IO, you could vacuum multiple tables concurrently. Don't wait, get started asap before the database shuts down

Comment: https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/managing-transaction-id-wraparound-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a manual `VACUUM` of individual tables will do the trick.

Look at the `relfrozenxid` and `relminmxid` columns in the `pg_class` entries for that database. Find the oldest ones. One or more of these should be equal to `datfrozenxid` and `datminmxid` in `pg_database`. If you `VACUUM` those tables, the values for the database should advance.